How to prioritize on multiple SQL function MIN()
I have columns DATE, LOC_NO, PART_NO. The query is grouped by PART_NO, I want a query prioritized by the MIN(DATE). I need also the value of LOC_NO but I don't care the value returned, then I used MIN(LOC_NO).
My question: does the order of MIN() function matter? I want the highest priority for MIN(DATE).
My query is :
SELECT
    PART_NO,
    MIN(DATE),
    MIN(LOC_NO)

instead of
SELECT
    PART_NO,
    MIN(LOC_NO),
    MIN(DATE)

Example data

I want the result is the row 1 instead of row 3.

When you say "prioritized" do you mean "ordered by"? Could you show us some sample data and your expected results, please?

" I need also the value of LOC_NO but I don't care the value returned" - if you don't care about the value of LOC_NO why do you want to return it?

@Dai I created a validation, if the current transaction is greater DATE to the other part no existed on system, the transaction is canceled along with tell to User the location of the part with lower DATE. It is used for FIFO validation.

@Johan That doesn't answer my question.

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question

Simple answer, i need the value of 'LOC_NO' to show to Users where is the location of the lowest DATE with the same part no. example message : "FIFO violation on part no : 1234ABCD. There is Lowest GR Date on location AB01XX"

Do the aggregations of A_DATE and LOC_NO separately
One option could be to filter the result using inner join of the table and the subquery aggregating Min(A_DATE) grouped by PART_NO:
With   --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (PART_NO, A_DATE, LOC_NO) AS
        ( Select 'ABC123', DATE '2024-06-01', 'AB01CC' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'ABC123', DATE '2024-06-02', 'AB01CC' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'ABC123', DATE '2024-06-03', 'AB01AA' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'ABC123', DATE '2024-06-04', 'AB01DD' From Dual
        )

--    S Q L :
Select  t1.PART_NO, t1.A_DATE, Min(t1.LOC_NO) "LOC_NO"
From    tbl t1
Inner Join (  Select    PART_NO, Min(A_DATE) "A_DATE"
              From  tbl t
              Group By PART_NO  ) t2 ON(t2.PART_NO = t1.PART_NO And
                                        t2.A_DATE = t1.A_DATE)
Group By t1.PART_NO, t1.A_DATE

/*      R e s u l t :
PART_NO A_DATE   LOC_NO
------- -------- ------
ABC123  01.06.24 AB01CC   */

Another option is to use Where clause to filter the result:
--    S Q L :
Select  t.PART_NO, t.A_DATE, Min(t.LOC_NO) "LOC_NO"
From    tbl t
Where   (t.PART_NO, t.A_DATE) = (  Select   PART_NO, Min(A_DATE) "A_DATE"
                                   From     tbl t
                                   Group By PART_NO  ) 
Group By t.PART_NO, t.A_DATE


Perfect, it's what I'm looking for.
